# How can I use registerDefaults: properly, to load my default settings?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I've been told that I need to use the registerDefaults: to load the NSUserDefaults if the user has never changed the app settings.

In my AppDelegate I am using the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Load default defaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Defaults" ofType:@"plist"]]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I copied the Root.plist of my settings bundle to the ressources folder of my project and renamed it Defaults.plist

Now in the viewDidLoad method of my view controller i'm using the following code to load the settings:

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

```
if ((([[defaults objectForKey:kToggleSwitch] isEqualToString:@"Enabled"]) ? YES : NO)) {

//Do Stuff
//BTW i'm using strings for the True/False the values of the ON/OFF positions of the UISwitch

}
```

Even with doing all this, my default settings stored in the Root.plist of my settings bundle don't get loaded. The only way they load is if the user actually goes into the iPhone settings and simply views my app's settings page.

Clearly i'm doing something wrong here can someone help me out. Btw i'm running it using iOS 4.1

Comment: what is in your Defaults.plist file?

Comment: it should be a dictionary with with kToggleSwitch set to what ever is the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when I made my app, i never knew of any defaults to be registered, so I made a poor man's defaults:

I have a bool variable: haveConfig, which is checked when the settings are loaded:

```
haveConfig = [prefs boolForKey:@"haveConfig"];
if (!haveConfig)
{
    return;
}

/* Load settings here */
....
```

First time the "haveConfig" will be false, so I don't load them. When the user first changes one of the settings, they are stored together with the "haveConfig" variable:

```
haveConfig = true;
[prefs setBool:haveConfig forKey:@"haveConfig"];
...
```

I know it's not perfect, but it works :-)

Comment: that seems like a clever idea. But how can do I know if the settings were loaded, in order to change the bool to true?

Comment: When they change the settings for the first time, i save the bool with true value. Next time the (!haveConfig) condition is true when the settings will be loaded :-)